# Using Spring EL to set value as lambda

Tags: java, xml, lambda, predicate, spring-el

I want to create a `<map></map>` property via Spring XML configuration. This `Map` should hold a key of type `String` and a Value of type `Predicate`. I could now create some specified classes implementing `Predicate` but I want to avoid this boilerplate.

I would like to pass a lambda value via *Spring Expression Language*. I read about [FunctionalReferences Spring](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/FunctionReference.html) but it I can not get my head around it just yet.

**Actual implementation**:

```
  <constructor-arg>
      <map> 
         <entry key="FormElement#viewtype" value="#{<!-- what to do here -->}"></entry>
      </map>
  </constructor-arg>
```

**Understanding the linked documentation I tried something like this:**

```
 <constructor-arg>
      <map> <!-- Map<String, Predicate<Object>> -->
         <entry key="FormElement#viewtype" value="{|object|$object == 'fooView'}"></entry>
      </map>
  </constructor-arg>
```

**Error**: `<expression> expected, got '|'`

I understand that the *expression* language expects an expression but I really would like to pass a lambda as value here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Javadoc is incorrect; Lambdas didn't make the final cut in SpEL [commit here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/95892dc993957f01431a650a5f2f3408e267dcb4).

Comment: Ah noooo my whole idea is now destroyed :(
Have you some recommendations to solve my problem otherwise but still elegant?